What is the difference between extract_if and previously drain_filter?
I have some old code which uses Vec::drain_filter a lot. When updated to a newer toolchain, it seems that drain_filter feature is already removed.
I found no explanation about this in rust's official documents. Seems the page is just removed. I found some "mirror" of previous version, and it does not say the interface is deprecated and will later be removed.
However, from this post, I found the drain_filter has actually equivalent extract_if. Seems they all accepts some iterator, and filter only the elements which satisfy given predicate.
My question is what makes the difference between drain_filter and extract_if and why we removed drain_filter?

From the thread you linked, more explicit version. tldr: the drain-on-drop behaviour turned out to be an issue, because if the filter panics it still needs to be called again to finish draining, which creates high odds of double panic and abort. Drain-on-drop was thus removed from the API, which had to be renamed as it's a strong component of the drain API language.

I found some "mirror" of previous version, and it does not say the interface is deprecated and will later be removed. - it does say it's "experimental" and "nightly-only". By using such features (and the nightly channel) you accept the possibility of them getting renamed, reworked into something else, or even disappearing altogether.

@user4815162342 I am not complaining about this, I just want to know in what consideration this change take place.

@calvin Fair enough, but that's my point - "nightly" means that it can be done with no (publicly visible) consideration whatsoever. Normal rules of deprecation cycle just don't apply, which is one of the reasons most users should probably avoid nightly Rust.

The drain_filter function was an nightly only, experimental API. As the name implies, these can be changed at any time with no backwards compatibility guarantees, as happened here.
drain_filter was changed because of the following problem with its API design:
If the filter function panics, the DrainFilter iterator is dropped, which causes it to attempt to process the remaining elements, for which it has to call the filter function again, likely leading to a nested panic -> abort.
(See this issue comment for more details).
The api was changed to make drain_filter no longer process the remaining elements on drop.
Because of this change, calling the function drain_filter would now be misleading, because the basic drain API that it alludes to behaves fundamentally different (it drains on drop). It was therefore renamed to extract_if.
If this change is not relevant for you, because you always process all elements of the container yourself, you can use extract_if with no change in behavior (assuming no panics happen in your filter functions).
